# Real 3D interior room from 360 images

Tags: 3d, virtual-reality

If I have 360 images of an interior room from all different angles, would it be possible with current 3D software technology to create a **real** 3D representation of that room, where the camera could freely navigate to any part of it?

So similar to Photoshop’s stitch, where you stitch a bunch of photos to create a single 360 photo, would you be able to stitch a bunch of 360 photos to create a 3D environment?

I’m not looking to create graphics or photorealism out of the room, but rather the actual real room. Most of my research points either to one of the above or VR videos, which have limitations on camera direction.

If it is possible, could you please point me to the right direction/software and/or examples of work that have achieved this?

If it’s not possible, I would be very interested in knowing what the limitations are.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this sort of thing is commonly done, it's called photogrammetry. If you google that you'll find a lot about it, and plenty of software. I haven't used any of it myself so I can't recommend a particular program, but most likely there's something out there that will serve your purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A website devoted to prescanned photogrammetry is :[Quixel.com](https://quixel.com) They did (at least some of) the assets for the version 5 unreal engine [demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qC5KtatMcUw).

I have gotten excellent results with software from [Agisoft](https://www.agisoft.com) but it costs real money.
For good free software try [3DF Zephyr](https://www.3dflow.net)

This software will just generate the mesh, they will provide only minimal navigation of the result which is outside the scope of generation.

To navigate the mesh you can use something like windows 3D viewer.

Or better yet, and way more fun, write your own!

Comment: This is amazing information! Thank you both pmw1234 and Nathan Reed! I will take that information and try things out! Cheers!